# Model viewer: Uncaught TypeError: N.ajax is not a function when using jQuery Slim

Tags: autodesk-viewer

We've recently started moving away from jQuery's full package toward slim. This removes much of the bloat from jQuery replaced by more modern api's like XHR or fetch in place of .ajax.

There seems to be an issue even in viewer3D 4.0.1 that appears when attempting to use jQuery Slim. Here's the stack trace:

```
viewer3D.min.js?v=v4.0.1:30 Uncaught TypeError: N.ajax is not a function
    at Object._fetchOne (viewer3D.min.js?v=v4.0.1:30)
    at String.<anonymous> (viewer3D.min.js?v=v4.0.1:30)
    at Object.each (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at String.<anonymous> (viewer3D.min.js?v=v4.0.1:30)
    at Object.each (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at Object._fetch (viewer3D.min.js?v=v4.0.1:30)
    at Object.load (viewer3D.min.js?v=v4.0.1:30)
    at Object.g [as init] (viewer3D.min.js?v=v4.0.1:30)
    at Object.c.setLanguage (viewer3D.min.js?v=v4.0.1:44)
    at Object.c.initializeLocalization (viewer3D.min.js?v=v4.0.1:44)
```

This bug appears only when using jQuery Slim. If I use full, or remove jQuery altogether it does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery slim](https://jquery.com/download/) excluded ajax and effect, as per their documentation.

If you are using jQuery to request access tokens, then use the regular library.

**EDIT**

The Forge Viewer seems to be using jQuery when it's available, but jQuery slim is causing this problem. We're investigating it. (As of March 2018)

**EDIT 2**

Just [released v4.1](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-release-notes-v41) with this fix (April 5, 2018). Thanks for reporting it.

Comment: You've missed the point. I'm well aware of their removal ajax. That's why I went with it. My own code uses fetch. However the model viewer code in viewer3D.min.js?v=v4.0.1:30 **assumes** that if jQuery is present, it includes jQuery.ajax. That's the bug I'm pointing out. 

They have the ability to work without jQuery, or with it. But if it's present, but includes no ajax methods.

Comment: I confirm that as of version 7.x of the Autodesk Forge viewer this is also an issue. Using a non-slim version "fixes" the problem.